# my page resize alone when I close bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

when I close the bootstrap modal the page will resize I try to make the body position fixed but I will not see all the result on the page
[image: here is a photo]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] (and earn a badge while you are at it) / Also read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community.  For starters, please include a [mcve] to your question. Otherwise, it might take a lot more time and a heap of guessing to figure *exactly* where the issue lies.

Comment: Try to add `position: relative` to the div which contains the modal

Comment: didn't work with me